# Modern replacement for libaosd?

Tags: linux, x11, void-linux

I used to use `aosd_cat` to write large messages across the screen, [like so](https://screenshots.debian.net/package/aosd-cat).

It is based on [`libaosd`](https://github.com/atheme-legacy/libaosd) which is unmaintained for years, and apparently requires equally ancient hacks like "infinality" patches to build.

Is there a modern replacement for it?

(Yes, I know that Debian still ships it. But I'm running Void Linux, which does not.)

Comment: What functionality do you specifically need? Is a notification daemon insufficient?

Comment: @CameronNemo: I specifically want the ability to write in _huge_ letters across the screen, as shown on the screenshot. This is a very different form of notification than, say, what `notify-send` offers.